# Programming C++ on Mac

Tags: c++

I just wanted to ask, if anyone knows how you could program C++ on Mac. Can you use Xcode for doing this? I read you could use CommandLine Tool in Xcode but I don't know how to do the UserInterface then. Would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While all of us here very much appreciate that you are joining the programming community, you might get a little heat for this question because it is not strictly about solving a specific programming problem you have. It sounds like you need a tutorial, and your question is not really well formatted for StackOverflow.

Comment: Sure.  Just fire up Xcode and add C++ files to a project.  The user interface API is Objective C, so you will have to use Objective C for the interface.

Comment: I believe the Xcode command line tools install emacs in the terminal, but Xcode should have an option to make C++ projects.  My Google search says there are a bunch of videos on this topic, you may want to start in Google before asking a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to start C++ coding namely command line and using IDE like Xcode. I suggest you to start via command line which means you need a C++ compiler (i.e. g++ compiler for free) and an editor (for Mac users, ppl generally use textWrangler editor). IDEs hide a lot of stuff for the sake of simplicity, so as a beginner, you should start with command line to see how C++ compilation flows. Let's say you got g++ compiler and textWrangler.

First: Open textWrangler editor and create a new document and name it `main.cpp`

Second: type the following in your `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << " Hello World! " << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Third: open the terminal (i.e. in utilities folder)

Fourth: move to the directory where your `main.cpp` is in using `cd` command

Fifth: type `g++ main.cpp -o output`

You will notice a file in the directory of your `main.cpp` whose name is `output`. This is the executable file. This is the final step for compiling C++ code. To run it  type `./output`. You will see `Hello World!` in your terminal. If you got confused then you might find YouTube is a best way to go.